FindWindowA не может найти окно
Я использую FindWindowA, моя задача найти открытое окно и закрыть его, но почему-то он не может найти окно с именем "Roblox".
Так же я пробовал использовать FindWindowEx и FindWindow, но ситуация такая-же, ничего не получается найти.
Вот кусочек с использованием FindWindowEx:
auto hwnd = ::FindWindowEx(0, 0, L"Roblox", 0);
Вот кусочек с использованием FindWindow:
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(L"Roblox", 0);
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <memoryapi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
 HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Roblox");

   if (hwnd == NULL) {
     cout << "Not found app";
     Sleep(1000);
   } else {
       DWORD procID;
       GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
       auto handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);
       if (procID == NULL) {
           cout << "Cannot obtain process!" << endl;
           Sleep(3000);
       } else {
           TerminateProcess(handle, 1);
           CloseHandle(handle);
       }
 }

  return 0;
}



почему-то он не может найти окно с именем "Roblox" Скорее всего, имя окна просто не совпадает с вашим мнением о нём... Или это не топ, а дочка, а их FindWindowA не ищет, используйте FindWindowEx.

Попробуйте с помощью Spy++ поискать нужное окно.

FindWindowEX пробовал не помогает

Roblox - такое окно точно существует? x(икс) - это точно икс, а не "ха" на кириллице?

На на английском и такое окно существует
